# Do any document databases (noSQL) allow you to do cross database joins?

Tags: nosql, document-oriented

I am currently looking at MongoDB and ArangoDB as the database for our web application, but neither appear to support cross-database joins, does anyone know if there is such a document database that supports this please?

Comment: You could try PostgreSQL? Using the [postgres_fdw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448/470530) (foreign data wrapper) and the querying capabilities with JSONB?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it postgres

**Update as of 9.3**

You can now use the new [postgres_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) (foreign data wrapper) to connect to tables in any Postgres database - local or remote.

also you can use **dblink** functionality but it isn't part of the default PostgreSQL install, but you can add it in.-  [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html).